# Can every dynamical system be interpreted in terms of (unitary) conjugation in an operator algebra

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $X$ be a compact Hausdorff  space with a homeomorphism $\alpha: X \to X$. Assume that $C(X)$ is  a  commutative sub algebra of $B(H)$, namely $C(X)$ is embedded in $B(H)$.

Is there an invertible or unitary element $T\in B(H)$  such that $TfT^{-1}=f\circ\alpha^{-1}\quad \forall f \in C(X)$?

The motivation comes from the definition of the cross product algebra $C^*(X,\alpha)$ as the universal algebra generated by $C(X)$ and a unitary element $u$ subject to the relation $ufu^*=f\circ \alpha^{-1}$. See page $2$ [of this poster](http://www.math.s.chiba-u.ac.jp/~matui/1307busan.pdf).

Note that the answer is affirmative when $H$ is a finite dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: Not always, even with $H$ finite-dimensional. For instance take $X$ with 2 elements and $\alpha$ not the identity. Embed $C(X)$ into $B(H)$ (with $\dim(H)\ge 3$) by mapping the two nontrivial idempotents to commuting idempotents that are not conjugate.

Comment: @YCor  Yes Thank you! I realize you mean that the representation $\begin{pmatrix} x&0&0\\0&y&0\\0&0&y\end{pmatrix}$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is  a counter example.But  what kind of conditions  can we impose on embedding of $C(X)\subset  B(H)$ such that the question has an affirmative answer?Any way the question introduce us  a  particular subgroup of homeomorphism group of a topological space $X$.

Comment: @YCor  Is there an (increasing) homeomorphism $\alpha:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ and an embedding of $C([0,1])$ in some $B(H)$ such that $\alpha$ can not be interpreted in terms of unitary  conjugation?

Comment: I guess yes, but don't immediately see. Maybe a comment is not the best place to ask/answer such a question.