# Commutative subalgebras of $B(H)$ whose all automorphisms are in the form of unitary conjugation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space.

Is there a compact Hausdorff space $X$ such that $C(X)$ is embeded in $B(H)$ and for every homeomorphism $\alpha$ of $X$ there exist a unitary operator $u\in B(H)$ with $u^*fu=f\circ \alpha^{-1}\quad \forall f \in C(X)\subset B(H)$?

The motivation comes from the following post:

[Can every dynamical system be interpreted in terms of (unitary) conjugation in an operator algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338155/can-every-dynamical-system-be-interpreted-in-terms-of-unitary-conjugation-in-a)

Comment: Yes, the one point space. I assume you actually wanted to ask something more specific?

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes I mean non degenerate space.

Comment: @YemonChoi a space with at least 3 point. However infinite space or even connected space would be ideal examples.

Comment: @YemonChoi  One can generalize the question in a more algebraic manner as follows: For a goven $C^*$ algebra $A$, one can think to all subalgebras $B$ such that every automorphism of $B$ is in the form of a unitary conjugation.

Comment: I guess that every sutomorphism of $\mathbb{K}$ must be a unitary conjugation.

Comment: Can't you just take any faithful representation of the $C^*$-algebra $C(X) \rtimes {\rm Homeo}(X)$?

Comment: @JessePeterson  may you elaborate your comment? Why such faithful representation in $B(H)$  which contains a copy of $C(X)$ solve my question?

Comment: @JessePeterson  Am I mistaken to get some thing from your comment? Every automorphism of $C(X)$ has an extension to an automorphism of the cross product. Now since the representation is faithfull every authomorphism should be the restriction of a unitary conjugation. I am not sure if i get what you meant in your comment. Am i mistaken?

Comment: Yes, ${\rm Homeo}(X)$ is implemented on $C(X)$ by inner automorphisms in $C(X) \rtimes {\rm Homeo}(X)$. You can find the $C^*$-crossed product construction in many books on $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: @JessePeterson Thank you. I read the definition of  C^* dynamical system in the book of "C^* algebra by examples" many years ago. But just 1 question: Why every automorphism of a subalgebra of B(H) is in the form of a conjugation?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I don't understand your question. Can you make it more precise?

Comment: @JessePeterson  Ok, according to your first comment, and  considering my question in the post, my inspiration was that you mean every automorphism of $A\subset B(H)$ is in the form of a unitary authomorphism. may be I am mistaken?